# How to know a metric space is complete if I don't know if it contains all its limits?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

For any $x\in X$ if $h(x)$ maps every $x$ to the equivalent class of the constant sequence of $x$ and $\hat{X}$ is the set that contains all equivalent classes of the Cauchy sequences of $X$, then the disjoint union $\tilde{X} =X\cup\hat{X}\setminus h(X)$ is a complete metric space containing $X$ as a dense subspace.

I already prove $\hat{X}$ is a complete metric space and $h(X)$ is dense in $\hat{X}$ but I don't know how to prove the theorem above. In particular, if a Cauchy sequence from $\tilde{X}$ contains only elements from $X$ then I don't know if it has a limit in $\tilde{X}$ since I wasn't told $X$ is complete. This is different from proving $\hat{X}$ is complete where I can construct a limit. I know this is a famous result, so if I miss any detail in the description please correct me and of course left some comments on how to prove the theorem above.

Thanks.

Comment: $\tilde X$ is isomorphic to $\hat X$, it just has the elements of $h(X)$ replaced by their representatives from $X$ so that $X$ is "literally" a subspace. You just need to make sure that the metric defined on $\tilde X$ achieves the desired replacement.

Comment: @Karl Yes, but the metric $\tilde{\rho}$ I was given for $\tilde{X}$ is that $\tilde{\rho}(u,v)=\rho(u,v)$ if $u,v\in X$, $\tilde{\rho}(x_n,y_n)=\lim\rho(x_n, y_n)$ if $x_n, y_n\in\hat{X}\setminus h(X)$, and $\tilde{\rho}(x_n,u)=\lim\rho(x_n, h(u))$ if $x_n\in\hat{X}/h(X)$ and $u\in X$.  I intuitively get the idea of isometry but I don't know how to make sense  w.r.t this metric when $u,v\in X$. Note. $x_n, y_n$ should be in two individual cauchy sequences which either in same class or different class, and $\rho$ is a metric defines on $X$.

Comment: Hmm, do you see that $\tilde\rho(x,y)=\hat\rho(h(x),h(y))$?

Comment: @Karl No if you are talking for $x,y\in X$ and $\hat{\rho}(\{x_n\}, \{y_n\})=\lim\rho(x_n, y_n)$ where $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ are two cauchy sequences in $X$.

Comment: @Karl I totally don't know why he [author who gave the question] gives this metric at the end rather than just conclude that the completion of $X$ which is $\hat{X}$ contains $X$ as a dense subspace given that $h: X\to\hat{X}$ is an isometry and we know $\hat{X}$ is complete.